# How to prevent app changing powershell background color?

Tags: powershell

Powershell uses dark blue as its default background color. However, gcc form mingw sets background to black for its output, which makes the console ugly. Is there any way to disable programs form changing the background? (better only one specific app)

Comment: Are you positive that the background color is being set, and this isn't the case, of two different environments?  If you set the background, after the console with the incorrect color is launched, does the color remain the same the next time it launches?

Comment: @Ramhound Whatever I set, gcc output remains on black background, and after that other programs are using original color.